# After upgrade to laravel 5.3 error invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Tags: laravel, date, timestamp, migration

I upgraded my project to laravel 5.3 from 5.2. Now when I want run `php artisan migrate` I receive error:

> **SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime
>   value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'created_at' at row 1 (SQL:
>   alter table `messages` add `deleted_at` timestamp null).**

My migration:

```php
  Schema::table(Models::table('messages'), function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->softDeletes();
  });
```

In Blueprint.php:

```php
    public function softDeletes()
    {
        return $this->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable();
    }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Laravel 5.3 was updated to use MySQL "strict" mode by default, which includes the `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode.

The issue is that your existing data was allowed to have '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as a datetime value. But, now your connection is using a sql mode that does not allow that value (`NO_ZERO_DATE`). When you attempt to alter the table to add the `deleted_at` column, it is complaining about the existing data violations in the `created_at` column.

The ideal solution would be to fix all the data in the database. That is, go through your database and update your datetime/timestamp fields so that they are nullable, and convert their data from '0000-00-00 00:00:00' to null.

However, the quick option is to just disable "strict" mode on your database connection. Open your `config/database.php` file, and make sure your database connection shows `'strict' => false`.

Comment: 'strict' => false - this helped me. Thank you. But when I deleted all data from my database I had the same error.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem when adding a datetime column in a table with timestamps (created and updated_at).

I solved just adding the '->nullable($value = true)' modifier in my migration:

`$table->datetime('expires_at')->nullable($value = true);`

I understood that the database complained about inserting all that zeros if the input dont come. Add the instruction to be nullable did the trick.

Comment: it worked for me.but can you explain why it works?

Answer (score 4):

I like creating the default as `NOW()` anyways.

So `$table->datetime('expires_at')->default(NOW());` is also a good option.

Answer (score 2):

This error Cause by STRICT_TRANS_TABLES and NO_ZERO_DATE in sqlmode for mysql 5.7

disabled it and in this way all things work correctly .

Answer (score 0):

Basically, running an update Migration tries to add a default deadline of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` to the existing records. However, mysql => 5.7 is strict hence does not permit this.

Solution

1. Fastest way is to **empty** the table (if the data is not very important)
2. Add. a default time now() when creating the migration like:
    `$table->dateTime('deadline')->default(now());`
3. Make it a **nullable** field.
4. or go with @Hossein's answer above