# Laravel migration rename dateTime column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, doctrine, migration

I want to rename a column using Laravel 5.6 migration for refactoring a legacy app. The column is:

```
`data_adaugarii` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I want to rename it to 'created_at'. For this I used the following code:

`Schema::table('cp', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('data_adaugarii', 'created_at');
});`

Running the migration, I receive the following error:

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: 'current_timestamp()' for column 'created_at' at row 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE cp CHANGE data_adaugarii created_at DATETIME DEFAULT 'current_timestamp()' NOT NULL)

Has anyone encored this problem?

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946607/after-upgrade-to-laravel-5-3-error-invalid-datetime-format-1292-incorrect-datet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change mode in `config/database.php` to `false` in `mysql` array

```
'strict' => false
```

Comment: Now I get: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'created_at' (SQL: ALTER TABLE cp CHANGE data_adaugarii created_at DATETIME DEFAULT 'current_timestamp()' NOT NULL)

Comment: I read that, thanks. I finally used a custom query to do my migration, like this: DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec('ALTER TABLE `cp` CHANGE `data_adaugarii` `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;');