# Error when using the format: $table->date('column_name') in Laravel

Tags: laravel, date, timestamp, database-migration

I'm having some trouble with date formats in Laravel.
I have a database migration which has a field that looks like the following:

```
$table->date('Date');
```

Then, in the controller, I try to fill this field in with the following content:

```
2019-04-15
```

But I get the following error:

```
invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '"2019-04-15"' for column 'Date' at row 1
```

Any help on which would be the correct way of declaring the field 'Date' in the database would be apreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can u post controller and migration code?

Comment: Please show the exact code how you are setting the date in controller to make it more clear and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with strict date typing in MySQL I believe.

Check these answers for more information.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946950/1848660

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48998959/1848660

Answer (score 0):

Try using Carbon to generate dates and timestamps.

This will generate a timestamp for the current date and time.

```
Carbon\Carbon::now();
```

Or you can parse your current date and convert it to a Carbon stamp

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->toDateTimeString();
```

Documentation: 
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

This works with your case:

```
 $date = "2019-04-15";

 $formatted_date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($date))->format('Y-m-d');
```

You can go ahead and test your insert. I have tested this. You won't face the 1292 Incorrect date ERROR.

```
  DB::table('yourTable')->insert(['date'=> $formatted_date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
$table->date ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($table->date)) : '-';
```

You should convert your date to string and then apply date function on that for different date format.